# Proving $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=nz$, for $z(x,y)=x^nf(\frac{y}{x^2})$. Where is my calculation wrong?

Tags: derivatives

> Given the function $z(x,y)=x^nf(\frac{y}{x^2})$ where is $f$ a differentiable function. Prove that equation:
> $$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=nz \tag{$\star$}$$

My attempt is:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=x^{n-1}f\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)(n-y)\quad\rightarrow\quad x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=x^{n}f\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)(n-y) \tag1$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^{n-2}f\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)\quad\rightarrow\quad 2y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2yx^{n-2}f\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right) \tag2$$

But $(\star)$ not meet. Wrong is my, or wrong is the $(*)$? Maybe it should be
$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+x^2y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=nz \tag{$\star$}$$

Comment: You missed $f'$.

Comment: where missed, the first derivation

Comment: In both derivatives you need $f'$.

Comment: $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=nx^{n-1}f(\frac{y}{x^2})-yx^{n-1}f(\frac{y}{x^2})=x^{n-1}f(\frac{y}{x^2})(n-y)$

Comment: wrong is my, or wrong is in the book

Comment: Apply the chain rule when taking the derivatives of $f(y/x^2)$!

Comment: my wrong is the find derivation of $1/x^2$

Comment: You missed $f'$ - as is written in very first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=$$
$$nx^{n-1}f(\frac{y}{x^2})-x^nf'(\frac{y}{x^2})\frac{2y}{x^3}$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^{n-2}f'(\frac{y}{x^2})$$

thus

$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=nz-2yx^{n-2}f'(\frac{y}{x^2})$$

$$=nz-2y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{l}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=nx^{n-1}f(\frac{y}{x^2})-2yx^{n-2}f'(\frac{y}{x^2}) \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^{n-2}f'(\frac{y}{x^2}) \end{array}$$
then easily (*) obtained.